# structured bindings to array element

Tags: c++, arrays, structured-bindings

What is the correct syntax of structured bindings when the left-hand side is a reference to an array member?

For example, the following program does not compile:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 2> f()
{
    return { 1, 2 };
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> a;
    a.fill(3);
    auto [ a[1], a[2] ] = f();
}
```

giving error

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:12:13: error: expected ']' before '[' token

   12 |     auto [ a[1], a[2] ] = f();
```

The same goes if the structured binding is written as

```
auto [ std::get<1>(a), std::get<2>(a) ] = f();
```

Comment: @bartop Well, transforming the array to a tuple and then using ```std::tie``` as in the linked question works to solve the specific program example. Or, even simpler, one could have f() to return a tuple instead of an array. But my question was explicitly on how to use structured bindings. If this is possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

structure binding declares **new** variables,

if you want to reuse existing variable, `std::tie` is more appropriate.

```
auto [ a1, a2 ] = f();
std::tie(a[1], a[2]) = std::tie(a1, a2);
```